# How to determine if a postgres view is updatable

Tags: database, postgresql, view

According to the documentation [Postgres > CREATE VIEW > Updatable Views](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html)
, a postgres view is updatable if following set of conditions are met:

> The view must have exactly one entry in its FROM list, which must be a table or another updatable view.
>
> The view definition must not contain WITH, DISTINCT, GROUP BY, HAVING, LIMIT, or OFFSET clauses at the top level.
>
> The view definition must not contain set operations (UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT) at the top level.
>
> The view's select list must not contain any aggregates, window functions or set-returning functions.

How do I programmatically determine, given a view `some_random_view` is updatable or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The information_schema.views data dictionary view contains the column is_updatable. The contents of this column tells you if the view is updatable or not.